# In g-computation after matching, do we mimic the formula used in matching even if you would have typically added more terms such as polynomial terms?

Tags: causality, matching, treatment-effect

I have some questions regarding best practices in g-computation post-matching in the standard case of a dichotomous treatment and a continuous outcome.

When defining the regression model with the matched data, I've read the following from the [MatchIt vignette in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html#estimating-treatment-effects-and-standard-errors-after-matching): (I didn't use propensity scores for the problem I'm working on, but I assume it is analogous)

> *...recommend only including the same terms included in the propensity score model unless there is a strong a priori and justifiable reason to model the outcome differently*.

Then, it is also recommended that in many cases we should add interaction terms with the treatment and covariates, like as follows:

```
#Extract matched data
md <- match.data(m.out)

#Linear model with covariates
fit1 <- lm(Y_C ~ A * (X1 + X2 + X3),data = md, weights = weights)
```

Thus, my interpretation is that the go-to practice, unless you have some strong reason to, is to only include the covariates used in the matching, X1 - X3, but you can add additional terms that are modifications of those covariates.

Would this mean that I can also add (or should add) polynomial terms for X1, if I know that X1 has a nonlinear relationship with outcome? My confusion comes from the fact in the actual matching process, polynomial terms might not be added to X1 depending on the matching specification - for example, it may be added if you're using logistic regression to estimate propensity scores, but not if you're using something like ANN to estimate the propensity scores as it does not require making assumptions about the functional form. But in g-computation, if using regression, would we "go back" to specifying interactions and polynomial terms? I would assume so, as one benefit I've heard of this framework is that the matching and treatment estimation are separated, but I'm not very confident in this.

To summarize, is the main focus that the same covariates are used in both steps, but however they are modified will just depend on what model is being used for the matching or the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the matching is to remove all imbalance in the covariates so that a simple difference in (weighted) means is unbiased for the treatment effect estimate. The g-computation step exists to reduce the residual variation in the outcome, which increases the precision of the treatment effect estimate for free. The goal of the outcome model therefore is not to correctly model the outcome but rather to reduce this residual variation while retaining the estimand.

One of the most important aspects of this analysis is that you do not respecify the outcome model. There is almost always a way to respecify the outcome model to get the desired effect estimate. Using a simple linear model with just the covariates you included in the matching tells your audience that you did not engage in this specification search to find the model that gives you the most "convenient" results. If I saw a squared term in the outcome model with no *a priori* justification, I would assume the analyst included it because without it they got a result they didn't like. To me, the justification needs to be strong and apparent (e.g., it is well known and demonstrable in the literature that a variable has a quadratic relationship with the outcome) in order to include such a term in the outcome model. Square terms rarely reduce the residual variation above and beyond the linear term; an exception would be when the relationship really is close to U-shaped. Even if the true relationship is quadratic, it might be that the reduction in residual variance is not worth the cost in precision of including an additional variable in the model.

If you want to do something sophisticated, you can. You can fit a machine learning model for the outcome, or even a flexible spline model. The key is to manage your audience's expectations and avoid performing analyses that will make your audience lose trust in your conclusions or invalidate the inferences. Using a linear outcome model does this best because it will tend to reduce most of the residual variation in the outcome without requiring the specification search that would otherwise be necessary to correctly model the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I think I had a misconception on the role of the outcome model post-matching. I have a follow-up question though - if we shouldn't respecify the outcome model, why is it that it is recommended to add interaction terms in the outcome model? Is it because no interaction was assumed in the matching process?

Comment: It isn't recommended to add interaction terms in the outcome model, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. The only interactions you should include in the outcome model are interactions between treatment and the covariates; this is necessary to retain the target estimand and ensure valid inference, though it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "necessary to retain the target estimand and ensure valid inference"? Is it related to this line in your vignette, "Note the interpretation of the resulting estimates as the expected potential outcomes is only valid if all covariates present in the outcome model (if any) are interacted with the treatment."? If so I'm confused about that as well - does that imply that you would only include the interaction with the treatment if you think that each covariate has an interaction with treatment?